# Hackerrank: Save the Prisoner

Tags: logic, modular-arithmetic

I am facing a problem in modular arithmetic.

Simplified problem statement:

> `n`: an integer, *the number of prisoners*
>
> `m`: an integer, *the number of sweets*
>
> `s`: an integer, *the chair number to begin passing out sweets from*
>
> The prisoners are seated around a circular table in sequentially
>   numbered chairs (numbering starts from 1).
>
> **Find the prisoner who receives the last sweet.**

I can think of many possible solutions but decided to try a one liner:

```
m % n + s - 1
```

My reasoning:

1. Distribute `m` sweets to `n` prisoners evenly. The remainder will be part of the last round of distribution.
2. Add the initial offset `s` to reach the last seat.
3. I had to subtract 1 from the result to pass some test cases *(I don't know the reason)*.

However, the formula fails for other test cases.

What is going wrong in the logic? How should I correct the formula?

Comment: The first sweet goes to seat $s$, the second sweet goes to seat $s+1$, ..., the $m^\text{th}$ sweet (the last one) goes to seat $s + m - 1$. But of course, the seat numbering goes in a circle from $1$ to $n$ then goes back to $1$, so we are working modulo $n$ (think of the classic 'clockwork arithmetic' analogy), so when we say "seat number $s + m - 1$", we really mean seat $s + m - 1 \pmod{n}$. So your code should be `(s + m - 1) % n`.

Comment: @JohnDon I tried `(s + m - 1) % n` but it failed for `n = 3, m = 7, and s = 3`. The output was `0` whereas the expected output is `3`. But thanks for making me understand the purpose of `-1` in my original code.

Comment: @Ardent_Coder I suspect the problem is that using `% n` gives a value in the range $0$ to $n - 1$ (which is still correct modulo $n$) but you are probably required to a value between $1$ and $n$. In other words, whenever the `(s + m - 1) % n` returns a $0$, you should return the number $n$. (You can probably still do this with a one-liner: e.g. in Python, `((s + m - 1) % n) or n`.)

Comment: @JohnDon I am working in C++ but I got your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have to subtract $1$ is to avoid what is known as a [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error) or "off-by-one" error. Suppose there is only $1$ sweet. Then starting at seat $s$ you know the last (and only) sweet will go to the pirsoner at seat $s$. But $m\%n+s$ gives the result $s+1$. You need the $-1$ adjustment in $m\%n+s-1$ to account for the fact that sweet $1$ is given to the prisoner at setat $s$, not at seat $s+1$.

The other thing you have to remember is that $m\%n$ gives a result between $0$ and $n-1$, so $m\%n+s-1$ will be between $s-1$ and $n+s-2$. But the seat numbers go from $1$ to $n$. You could adjust your formula to $(m+s-1)\%n$, which is correct most of the time, but gives the incorrect answer $0$ when $m+s-1$ is a multiple of $n$. I'll leave you to think about how to make another adjustment to this expression to get an answer that is correct in all cases.

Comment: Fencepost error was interesting to read, thanks. I followed your answer along with John's comments and passed the problem with this solution: `(m + s - 1) % n ? (m + s - 1) % n : n;`. I checked if `m + s - 1` is a multiple of `n` using the conditional operator and returned `n` if so.

Answer (score 0):

I have got `(m + s - 1) % n ? (m + s - 1) % n : n;` following the explanations of John and Gandal.

However, I was able to shorten it further using the concept of **Fencepost Error** introduced to me by Gandal.

1. This is obvious by now:

   `(m + s - 1) % n`
2. `%` outputs in the range:

   *[0, n-1]*
3. So, convert *all* the quantities in the operand with respect to **counting from zero**:

   `((m - 1) + (s - 1)) % n`
4. Then convert that answer with respect to **counting from one**:

   `(((m - 1) + (s - 1)) % n) + 1`

The final solution has passed all the test cases.

It is still short and a one-liner:

`(m + s - 2) % n + 1`